# Cron job PHP-script won't run

Tags: php, cron

Thanks for looking at this post.
My problem is that I can't make cron to run php script.
I don't want this job to look like

```
* * * * * lynx -dump http://www.somedomain.com/cron.php
or * * * * * wget http://www.somedomain.com/cron.php,
```

because this way, as I understand it will be run as apache user.
Rather I would like this file to have permissions 750(invisible for outside) and have it run as a user user_name.
So, I tried to put settings in /etc/crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * php /var/www/site1/json_renew.php >/dev/null
or */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/site1/json_renew.php
or */1 * * * * user_name php /var/www/site1/json_renew.php
or same from $crontab -e.
```

But the script just won't run, although it runs perfectly,
when run from command line:

```
$ php /var/www/site1/json_renew.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run a cron job as a particular user, install it in the crontab for that user. You can login to that user and run `crontab -e`. Also, you should use the full path to PHP as in your second example above.

Comment: @Michael Mior: Thanks for advice, but nope it won't run...

Comment: i would test as root, also take out the chucking out of output and add a mailto and see what gets sent (if anything)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the script ran fine when the URL was visited directly, and would run sometimes, seemingly randomly. Turns out it was host server resource issue. Hostgator wont run a cron job when I'm connected via SSH with Putty on 2 computers.

From their help pages "SSH access is limited to two simultaneous connections on Shared and Reseller plans. Note: Any cron jobs configured will require one of these sessions to be available in order to run, since cron jobs run under the same shell as SSH."

When I close the SSH connection, the cron job immediately runs.

Maybe your host has a similar rule?